# Copy column to TreeView

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I have a `ttk.Treeview` with multiple columns. I would like to copy a column from excel or some text editor, and paste it manually into a specific column of the `Treeview.` Is this even possible, and in that case, how?

If it's possible with a structure other than `ttk.Treeview`, that would be ok.

Comment: It should be possible, but there's nothing built-in. You'll have to do the work to make it happen.

Comment: ok thx, I'll have to work on that then.